# Can we change the RemoveAbandonedQuestions to handle deleted owners too?

Tags: feature-request, automatic-deletion

I just stumbled across this question [Why MySQL returned result does not take in place into a file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45182732/1839439) which has been posted by a deleted user. It has not been picked up by roomba for having 2 comments, one of which is also by a deleted user.
[image]

Would it possible to adjust the rules for `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` so that if the user is deleted the number of comments is irrelevant?

There is no chance to ask the user for clarification or to ask them to improve the post anymore.

[There are over 15000 such questions.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1085102/questions-escaping-from-auto-deletion-due-to-own-comments) <sub>Thanks Andre Silva</sub>

Comment: When the user is deleted, it usually happens. In this case, I can only guess that there was an answer that was also recently deleted.

Comment: @Braiam no deleted answers

Comment: Someone deleted the comments on that question, so it's gone now. I agree that Roomba should be way more proactive.